# Combine Search() and Filter() to Gallery Items in PowerApps

Tags: office365, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I'm looking for a way to combine Search() and Filter() in my PowerApps gallery. There are a handful of columns that we would like to Search any text contained within, however, there are 2 columns that are lookup columns (one being a people field that I want to search DisplayName). Is there a way to add both of these functions in the gallery so I can use a single searchbox to either search keywords contained in some columns, or filter other lookup columns?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can nest these, as each returns a table upon which the other could operate.

```
Filter(Search(...)...)
or
Search(Filter(...)...)
```